# escape carret sign '^' in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In form there is  a text field in which I want to restrict '^' sign.
I am trying to escape carret sign '^' in regular expression.
For e.g.

`"abcdef".match([^])` is returning true

please provide suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

To match the line beginning:

```
> 'abcdef'.match(/^/)
[ '', index: 0, input: 'abcdef' ]
```

To match literal `^`, escape it:

```
> 'abcdef'.match(/\^/)
null
```

To match literal `^` inside a class of characters, put it on any position except the first:

```
> 'abcdef'.match(/[xyz^]/)
null
> 'abcdef'.match(/[def^]/)
[ 'd', index: 3, input: 'abcdef' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.search(/\^/)` .Backslash '\' will remove the function of '^' .This way you can restrict.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. Regexes *must* be enclosed in `/` in JS, so it should be

```
"abcdef".match("/[^]/"); //gives null
```

Also, you don't need to embrace the `/` into a `[]`, you can just escape it with `\`:

```
"abcdef".match("/\^/"); //gives null
```

See the http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html for details

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the string contains a caret try

```
/\^/.test( "abcdef" ); // => false
/\^/.test( "^abcdef" ); // => true
/[^\^]/.test( "aslkfdjfs" ); // =>true as caret does not exist in string
```